# Norwegian booking cancellation

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, norway, norwegian-air-shuttle

I booked a flight from Oslo to Helsinki and I want to cancel it! How can I do that, and will I have to pay extra charges?

Comment: Have you booked a LowFare or Flex ticket?

Comment: I bought a LowFare ticket

Comment: According to http://norwegian.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35#Cancel "The booking can be cancelled without charge within 4 hours of making a booking. After 4 hours the booking is non-refundable."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Norwegian LowFare tickets for flights within the Nordic countries can be canceled without charge within 4 hours after the booking. After that, the tickets are non-refundable. If it's any help, you can however until 30 minutes before departure change the name, destination or time by paying a fee. Depending on whether or not you have further plans to fly, that may be a better solution that just leave the original ticket unused.

You can find all the change and cancellation regulations from Norwegian [here](http://www.norwegian.com/en/Nyttig-pa-reisen/Reisetjenester/Endre-reise/).

Comment: OK I read that page before but there is not much information about cancelling.

Comment: What exactly are you missing? It states that the ticket can only be canceled within 4 hours after booking.

Comment: I booked the flight more than 2 weeks ago now ! so it means that I can't canceled it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says.

Comment: so in your opinion what should I do ?

Comment: What you should do depends on what you're trying to achieve. I am not really able to follow your questions.

Comment: My first question was will I had to pay any charges ?

Answer (score 6):

The answer given by Tor-Einar Jarnbjo is correct, but I'll like to add some important, but little known information.

Regardless of reason for cancellation, you can get governmental taxes and charges reimbursed. No one gives away money for free and for fun, so you will have to fill out a [hard-to-find-form](https://www.norwegian.com/ssl/uk/customer-services/travel-information/irregularities/delays-/refund/), and pay a fee.